# django: Show a agreement page if user is new to the system

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I am building an application using django and I am using a single signon system as my authentication system. I want to make sure if user has never been to the site that means If I don't have a record in my table prior to creating a record show a agreement page and if user decline then don't log the user in to the system.

How can I access view from my middleware to get the agreement (yes/no)

```
    try:
        shib_user = ShibUser.objects.get(shib_username=username)
        user = shib_user.auth_user
        user.backend = "django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend"
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # I think this is where I should be calling my view?
        user = auth.authenticate(remote_user=username)
        user.shibuser_set.create(shib_username=username, shib_user_role=shib_uRole)
```

basically flow should be if user click sign in link -> check if this user is already exist in my auth_table if the user exist which means that user has already seen the agreement if not show the agreement and if agrees create the record in auth_user

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply using the `view` instead from the `middleware`.

Since the `user` is new to the `system`, there won't be any authenticated `session` created.

When the user arrives to the site, show him the Agreement form. When he agrees to the Agreement, you can now start create an `authenticated session` object. And this will get stored as the cookie.

And now you can check, if the `session` is authenticated using:

```
>> if request.user.is_authenticated():
       # show him the system
   else:
       # redirect him to some different template
```

This should be done in your `main` view.

Comment: I think he wants to show his agreement form whichever page the user stubmles on. The logic cannot be tied to only one view in this case.

Comment: basically flow should be if user click sign in link -> check if this user is already exist in my auth_table if the user exist which means that user has already seen the agreement if not show the agreement and if agrees create the record in auth_user.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to alter the view, there is a `process_view` method in the Middleware framework

[Middleware process view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-view)